# install django using vagrant with chef-solo provisioner

Tags: linux, django, bash, python-3.x, chef-infra

As an absolute **Chef** beginner I try to set up a vm with the latest python and django. I use the "ubuntu/trusty64" box and was surprised that its python3 version does not come with pip and pyvenv installed.
So I had to install the latest python version 3.4.3 from source, which seems to be working fine. But when trying to pip install django with chef, I always get the same error saying:

> Chef::Exceptions::Package: No candidate version available for django

my python3 recipe:

```
package "python"

execute "update system" do
   command "sudo apt-get update -y"
   not_if { File.exists?('/tmp/Python-3.4.3')}
end

execute "get dependencies" do
   command "sudo apt-get install -y build-essential libbz2-dev libncurses5-dev libreadline6-dev libsqlite3-dev libgdbm-dev liblzma-dev tk8.6-dev libssl-dev python3-setuptools"
   not_if { File.exists?('/tmp/Python-3.4.3')}
end

%w[ /opt/python /djenv ].each do |path|
directory path do
    owner 'vagrant'
    group 'vagrant'
    mode '0755'
  end
end

bash 'install-python3.4.3' do
   user 'vagrant'
   cwd '/tmp'
   code <<-EOH
     set -e
     wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.4.3/Python-3.4.3.tgz
     tar -xvf Python-3.4.3.tgz
     rm Python-3.4.3.tgz
     cd Python-3.4.3
     ./configure --prefix=/opt/python
     make
     make install
     EOH
     not_if { File.exists?('/tmp/Python-3.4.3')}
end

execute "set pyvenv environment to /djenv" do
   command "/opt/python/bin/pyvenv /djenv"
   only_if{File.exists?('/opt/python/bin/python3')}
end
```

the django recipe:

```
package 'django'

execute "activate env" do
   command "source /djenv/bin/activate"
end

execute "install django and gunicorn" do
   command "pip install gunicorn && pip install Django==1.8.3"
   not_if {File.exists('/vagrant/../manage.py')}
end

execute "deactivate" do
   command "deactivate"
end
```

I basicaly follow [this](http://vajrasky.net/2015/01/setup-django-with-python-3-and-nginx-in-vagrant/) tutorial and try to translate it into chef.

Comment: I guess, you don't understand what `package` means in chef recipe. https://docs.chef.io/resource_package.html

Comment: okay ..... so that would be a easy_install_package since there is no pip_package ?? or just leave the package declaration out ?
Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
package 'python3' #will install python
package 'python3-pip' #will install pip3

execute 'pip3 install django' do #install django from command line with pip
  not_if "pip3 list | grep django" #only if it is not installed yet
end
execute 'pip3 install gunicorn' do
  not_if "pip3 list | grep gunicorn"
end
```